# Hyperledger Fabric - How to create Channels via API and dynamically

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

As far as I have seen most Hyperledger Fabric examples deal with the idea to create channels and thus private ledgers to apply view and data restrictions between parties. (e.g. https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:LinuxFoundationX+LFS171x+3T2017/courseware/f0db5224eb0e4bbb8cc1e93a6819012c/8a27d35a4ae34e2ea5d2c43e8b3cb71c/?activate_block_id=block-v1%3ALinuxFoundationX%2BLFS171x%2B3T2017%2Btype%40sequential%2Bblock%408a27d35a4ae34e2ea5d2c43e8b3cb71c)

But as far as I know these channels can't be created/bootstrapped via API, only via scripting.

Two questions - If you have a lot of different parties like insurers and customers

1. How should one handle this situation without a Client API and
2. How to deal with these many channels/ledgers then in the future?

Thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

You can create a channel either with the peer CLI, or with using one of the SDKs.

Now, what really happens in both of them is that they simply issue a gRPC call to the ordering service's Broadcast gRPC service, with a custom crafted message that contains the identity material (PEMs) of the organizations, parameters, etc. (everything in the configtx.yaml)

So, if you just look at the implementation of how an SDK does that - you should be able to do that yourself.